# Accessing imported javascript functions from another imported script

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

For context, I am working on a website written using a drag and drop tool. Fortunately the website allows you to embed HTML, CSS and javascript.

I am hoping to embed a customised version of the timekit widget available here https://github.com/timekit-io/booking-js, that takes stripe payment before accepting bookings.

In order to do this, I need access to stripe functions from within my booking.js. It seems a simple way to do this would be by importing both the timekit widget as well as stripe js on the page, in the following way:

`<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>`

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"</script>`

`<script src="https://rawgit.com/Path/To/custom/booking.js" defer></script>`

If I want to access functions from inside the stripe import within booking.js, is this possible? For instance in other languages I could do something like this, from booking.js:

`import Stripe`

`var x = Stripe.someFunction();`

I understand this is oversimplified but i'm not from a web background and am unsure how this works. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to add Stripe exactly the way you have it and access it without needing an import call. What code have you tried? What specific error is occurring?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix this now. In order to so I just added `type="module"` to the script tag I was importing (stripe in this case).

This allowed me to access it as I wanted, without the need for an import statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

`import * as Stripe from 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/';`

in your **booking.js** as below:

```
  import * as Stripe from 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/';

  Stripe.someFunction();
```

Or you can make a module script in HTML pages:

```
<script type="module">
  import * as Stripe from 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/';

  Stripe.someFunction();
</script>
```

References: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: From that link. "This feature is only implemented natively in Safari, Chrome, and Edge at this time."

Comment: Hm, I just get a syntax error -
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`